# Proper way to write test for a method from a Rails model/decorator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I am using the rails [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) gem and am in the process of testing my decorator methods now with Rails' built-in MiniTest framework.

I have a `full_name` method in my `user_decorator.rb` class, and want to write a test for this method. I also have `first_name` and `last_name` attributes on my `User` model.

My question is, what's the proper way to test that I get the correct output?

The method looks like this:

```
def full_name
    first_name + ' ' + last_name
end
```

Which of the following ways is the correct way to test that I get the correct output from this method?

```
assert_equal 'Jourdan Bul-lalayao', @jourdan.full_name
```

or

```
assert_equal @jourdan.first_name + ' ' + @jourdan.last_name, @jourdan.full_name
```

To me, the first option seems correct; in the second option, it feels like I'm just writing the function again and testing the real function against that.

Though, I would love to have any thoughts, and perhaps any other suggestions that might be better!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you're populating the user, possibly.

The second option *is* writing the method again, because you're testing the method's output, and specifying its behavior.

The (potential) issue with the first way:

The output could be the same for that particular user, but might be different, say, for a user with a middle name, if the method implementation changes to include the middle name. If your test data doesn't change you may get a false positive.